# GoogleTokenResponse getRefreshToken() return null

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Using OAuth2.0 to authenticate user with access token however ***GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest*** return new access token but it return null for getRefreshToken token following is my code:

```
 GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPES)
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .setApprovalPrompt("force").build();

          String authorizeUrl =
                flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(CALLBACK_URI).build();
                System.out.println("Paste this url in your browser: \n" + authorizeUrl + '\n');

                GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest tokenRequest =
                        flow.newTokenRequest(dfaToken);
                         tokenRequest.setRedirectUri(CALLBACK_URI);
                         GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = tokenRequest.execute();

                GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                         .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
                         .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
                         .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
                         .build();              
                credential.setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);
    System.out.println(credential.getAccessToken());
    System.out.println(credential.getRefreshToken());
```

Is there any configuration we need to set up in our project??

Comment: The refresh token is only returned on the initial authorization. Try withdrawing permission and trying again